# How set multiple editing of data in SQL Server from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have simple asp.net web app. That has multiple users who can login and edit Info.  However, I have noticed when users are updating info at the same time.When data goes to the MS SQL DB the data is swapped.

**Example**

UserA was editing Item1, while UserB was editing Item2. On updating the info, it shows UserA was editing Item2.

On login User's Credentials are stored in a session

```
  HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("Username", rs["Username"].ToString());
```

Code below is used to call the procedure in DB

```
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con)) {
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_EditItem", con)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtItemInfo.Text;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtItemID.Text;

      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Query in the procedure

```
Update tb_Items 
set ItemName = @ItemName 
where ItemID = @ItemID
```

When a single user is updating the data, data is updated correctly.

What causes data to be swapped when multiple users are editing info?

Comment: What does 'swapped' mean?

Comment: In this context, Interchanged.

Comment: Sound you like have shared variables or resources or when editing that you load data from items not being edit or a flaw in your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Transaction and modify code as below

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con)) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_EditItem", con)) {
        using  (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction"))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtItemInfo.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtItemID.Text;

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```